# Remove active network interface, which i think is after starting docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

These network interface spawns which I think is after I created some docker container but
there network interface is still present even though I removed all those containers.

Why are these interface not removed even though I removed all the docker containers and even there images?

I searched some posts in stackoverflow they all gave the reasons for it not the solution to remove those .

Below I had posted images of ifconfig ,docker ps and docker network ls

Here's some screenshots to defend my question.

[image]

Here's the content of picture added below

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

$ sudo docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE

$ sudo docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
efaccb2da465   bridge    bridge    local
b1d7f70ce7ed   host      host      local
31b8f54f6010   none      null      local
```

[image]

[image]

Please point out if am missing anything or point me in some direction to solve this issue.

Comment: Pasting code, logs, error messages... in images is specifically pointed out as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). It is usually barely readable, it prevents people trying to help you to copy/paste your code and it impairs the search engine ability to index the content. Please edit your question and put those contents in code or quote blocks. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running OpenVPN server?

Comment: You are absolutely genius man!!, I dont know how you got to this but yes i installed openvpn , yet i didn't connected to anywhere but still i tried killall openvpn command, and all those instances where removed , Thanks man for the help . Could you point me to any resource to learn more about it .